# Logic behind using 12 column grid for responsive layouts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Many of the libraries which support responsive technique uses the 12 column grid system. e.g. the default Bootstrap grid system utilizes 12 columns

Is there any reason or logic behind using a 12 column system and not something else ?

Comment: The same reason things like eggs were sold by 12 in the past : 12 can be divided in 2, 3, 4 and 6

Comment: it is divisible by 2, 3, 4 and 6 without remainder.

Comment: That's also why hours were divided in 60 minutes...

Answer (score 3):

12 is a [superior highly composite number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number) which can be divided in 2, 3, 4 and 6, which makes it very convenient when you want to buy eggs or layout a page.

*(too bad our ancestors didn't decide to stick to the duodecimal system, far superior in practice over the decimal one as soon as you're past counting over your digits)*

Answer (score 1):

It's because 12 is dividable by 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 12 without remainder. Lot's of combinations to achieve desired layout. If you need more columns, use something bigger, like 24 or so.

Answer (score 1):

It's an important part of the **grid system**.

> Bootstrap includes a responsive, mobile first fluid grid system that
>   appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size
>   increases.

So it's not something you'll be using for mobile screens, but it's really handy if you want to code a bunch of smaller pieces in a row for bigger screens. It just breaks down everything in 12 pieces and gives you more flexibility design and code wise.

AND it's dividable as some have already mentioned which makes it also easier to work with. 
It's one of those things you'll start appreciating once you start developing a website that requires multiple columns on the same row for whatever reason that may be.

Cheers,